# what is the difference between the Argument Principle and Rouché's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

What is the difference between the Argument Principal and the Rouche's Theorem.

I am not sure when to use which one when I have a question for example:

How many roots of $z^4 + z^3 + 1=0$ lie inside $C=\{|z|=3/2\}$

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArgumentPrinciple.html

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RouchesTheorem.html

Answer (score 1):

Use whichever one you can get to work for the problem at hand.  In the example you gave,
you might note that $(3/2)^4 > (3/2)^3+1$, so Rouché should work.  If you had $1.3$ instead of $3/2$, it wouldn't be so easy.